# Java threads become sleeping in linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, threadpool

I'm coding "daemon"-like software, which do some things in the loop (login to somewhere, do some things and logout) using multithreading.
My application run about 1000-2000 threads and this threads do job.
So here is my htop log at first ~10 minutes:
[image: Before]

So you can see on the above screenshot that some number of threads is running (ordered by green R status)

But after some time this happens:
[image: After]

As you can see just one-three threads are running periodically (it seems like system slow down threads or make it sleeping).
Application run threads for small-time job (it's about 10 seconds to 1 minute) and after thread die Fixed Thread Pool Executor create new threads to do same job.
So as I understand it should be equal speed of threads execution at all times. But it slow down after ~10-20 minutes. Normally running threads in htop up to ~500-200-300-100 threads and down to ~3-30-60 threads at each time. But after this 10-20 minutes just only thread is executing. So can you tell me what is happens and how to fix that?

Comment: Deadlocks maybe? Also -- if you're using 2000 threads you have a design problem. You should really be using a thread pool or a producer / consumer model.

Comment: @Chris what do you mean by "a thread pool or a producer / consumer model"? I'm using thread pool now.

Comment: Perhaps they are all waiting for something, this seems quite reasonable. Have you tried dumping all the thread stacks? There is a way to send a signal to the JVM to dump the stacks of all threads (I don't know what it is).

Comment: Using 2000 threads is probably not efficient for memory usage, depending on the default stack size - you're probably wasting at least 2G of a (virtual) memory for thread stacks.

Comment: Use `jstack` to get a stack trace on the threads.  With 2000 threads, this will be a pretty sizable output.

Comment: @MarkR the same situation even if threads number is about 50-100. Also threads are waiting maximum for 1 minute for response but this sleeping happens once and forever.

Answer (score 1):

Are the threads accessing mysql?  I see it running at 100%... if a thread is waiting for I/O, the kernel will let it sleep until the data is ready.  If it was waiting on disk you'd likely see that reflected in the load average, so it might be waiting on network data (are your sockets etc. closing properly? are you getting blocked from whatever server you are connecting to remotely?  is your remote service hanging?) or mysql data (is your connection pool too small? is mysql incapable of handling the load?).

Comment: It uses mysql just once (before loading threads). MySQL is setup for high-load and threads which connects to remote server wait response just for 1 minute and after that die.